# Airflow change port in docker compose

Tags: docker, airflow

I have airflow running locally on port 8080 with the following docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:9.6
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
            - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"

    webserver:
        image: puckel/docker-airflow:1.10.9
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        environment:
            - LOAD_EX=y
            - EXECUTOR=Local
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
        volumes:
            - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
            # Add this to have third party packages
            - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
            # - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: webserver
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
            interval: 30s
            timeout: 30s
            retries: 3
```

However I need the port 8080 for another process. I tried updating to both `"8080:8081"` and `"8081:8081"` but neither worked, server would not respond. `"8080:8080"`, however, works like a charm. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you missed the only correct option. The syntax for ports is:

```
{host : container}
```

so in your case

```
8081:8080
```

should technically work. Assuming of course that airflow runs on port 8080 and has that one exposed (which it seems according to the dockerfile).

Comment: Derp, I figured it was something small like that. thank you!

Comment: How do we do this via the `airflow.cfg` config file? How do we plug that config file into the `docker-compose` YAML?

Comment: Hi @DBA108642 .. Can you please mention what fixed your code.. I'm facing the same issue ..

Answer (score 0):

You could change the HTTP port on the `webserver` command and update the Docker port mapping like this:

on the YAML:

```yaml
...
    command: webserver -p 9999
    ports:
        - "9999:9999"
```

Sometimes this comes handy if you need the container to start listening directly on a specific port and avoid port mappings in scenarios where you are also changing network configurations e.g. in the YAML `network_mode: host`.

This basically means you can use only `command: webserver -p 9999` and get rid of the `ports:` YAML completely.